# How to match regex pattern on single line only?

Tags: java, regex

I have the following regex and sample input:

http://regex101.com/r/xK9dE3

As you can see it matching the first "yo".  I only want the pattern to match on the same line (the second "yo") pattern with "cut me".

How can I make sure that the regex match is only on the same line?

Output:

```
Hi
```

Expected Output (this is what I really want):

```
Hi

yo keep this here

Keep this here
```

Comment: Use `Pattern.MULTILINE` <-- this allows `^` to match at the beginning of each line and `$` to match at the end of each line

Comment: great thanks....that is what I'm using is java Pattern object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `s` or `DOTALL` flag and change your regex to the following:

```
^.*?((\yo\b.*?(cut me:)[\s\S]*))
```

With the `DOTALL` flag enabled `.` will match newline characters, so your match can span multiple lines including lines before `yo` or between `yo` and `cut me`.  By removing this flag you can ensure that you only match the line with both `yo` and `cut me`, and then change the `.*` at the end to `[\s\S]*` which will match any character including newlines so that you can match to the end of the string.

http://regex101.com/r/sX2kL0

**edit:** Note that this takes a slightly different approach than the other answer, this will match the portion of the string that you want deleted so you can replace this portion with an empty string to remove it.

Comment: cool...this is essentially what I want to achieve because once I match that pattern (match excess stuff ) i do a replaceall(excess, "") on the pattern match, which is the excess which essentially keeps the stuff above.. Thx!

Answer (score 2):

You can use this regex with `s` (DOTALL) regex flag:

```
^.*?(?=yo\b[^\n]*cut me:)
```

#### Online Demo: http://regex101.com/r/oV3eP7

`yo\b[^\n]*cut me:` is lookahead pattern that makes sure that `yo` with word boundary and `cut me:` are matched in the same line.